# TextInput is missing in ScrollView in iOS but not in Android

Tags: ios, react-native, textinput

My TextInput is missing inside ScrollView for iOS. It works fine on android.
Included is the sample app using Playground.

https://rnplay.org/apps/KtTZ2g

You could see that android is showing the TextInput, but the iOS's one does not show it.

These kind of bugs is making me crazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the TextInput, be sure to provide a height:

```
<TextInput
   style={{flex: 1, color: 'black', height:40}}
   editable={false}
   defaultValue="+"
   underlineColorAndroid='#C8C7CC' />
```

https://rnplay.org/apps/a6i08w

Comment: thx. Just found it. It makes me more than 2 hours to figure it out.